# Simulate network failure / offline mode in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, bdd

I have some JavaScript in my app that detects when the network connection goes away and temporarily caches data in local storage, to be synced with the server when the connection is re-established.

I've been trying to find a way to test this end-to-end using Capybara, but I can't seem to find any way of either temporarily disabling the app server or switching the headless browser into offline mode. FWIW I'm using Poltergeist as the driver.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be tested? (I can test the JavaScript app using sinon to fake the server going away, but I'd like to be able to test it end-to-end with a headless browser if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team has stubbed out the Rack app to simulated errors from the server. It works well enough (in Firefox). Here are some relevant excerpts from the code:

```
class NoResponseRack
  attr_reader :requests

  def initialize disconnected_mode
    @disconnected_mode = disconnected_mode

    @requests = []
    @sleeping_threads = []
  end

  def call(env)
    @requests.push(env)

    case @disconnected_mode
    when :elb_pool_empty
      @sleeping_threads << Thread.current
      sleep 65
      @sleeping_threads.delete Thread.current
      [504, {}, ['']]
    when :server_maintenance
      [200, {}, ['status_message=Atlas is down for maintenance.']]
    else
      [999, {}, [""]]
    end
  end

  def wakeup_sleeping_threads
    @sleeping_threads.each &:wakeup
    @sleeping_threads.clear
  end
end

def go_disconnected_with_proxy disconnected_mode=:server_error
  if $proxy_server_disconnected
    puts 'going DISconnected'
    $current_proxy = NoResponseRack.new disconnected_mode
    rack_mappings.unshift([nil, "", /^(.*)/n, $current_proxy])

    $proxy_server_disconnected = false
  end
end

def rack_app
  Capybara::current_session.driver.app
end

def rack_mappings
  rack_app.instance_variable_get(:@mapping)
end
```

Comment: In the latest version of Capybara (2.4), the Rack app is wrapped in another object, so you need: `Capybara::current_session.driver.app.get_instance_variable(:@app)` to get the thing that has `@mapping` in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you stumbled on this question looking for a way to test offline / progressive web apps with Capybara and Chrome Headless, here's how:

```rb
params = {
  cmd:    'Network.emulateNetworkConditions',
  params: {
    offline:            true,
    latency:            0,
    downloadThroughput: 0,
    uploadThroughput:   0
  }
}
page.driver.browser.send(:bridge).send_command(params)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. Just in case someone wonders about these options: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-emulateNetworkConditions

params for going online are: { offline: false, latency: 0, downloadThroughput: -1, uploadThroughput: -1 }.

Just providing offline: true/false does not work, it needs all 4 options.

Answer (score 0):

About the only way I can think of would be to allow the host to be overridden in your tests, and give it a bogus host (something like localhost:31337).

Maybe have a look at http://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-capybara-to-test-javascript-that-makes-http and see if anything jumps out.

Answer (score 0):

I found also another option. To start Chrome with

```rb
options.add_argument('--host-resolver-rules=MAP * ~NOTFOUND')
```

I saw this in [chromium docs](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy/) because this flag was missing from `google-chrome --help`.

Which link also means that you can also use your own proxy server to simulate different conditions as well.